# jQuery bug elem is undefined if ( elem.nodeName ) {

Tags: jquery

You might saw my previous topic about jQuery upgrade. So finally we have upgraded the jQUery to 1.6.1 from 1.4.2 but we encountered the following issue:

```
elem is undefined

if ( elem.nodeName ) {
```

So does anyone know if this issue of jQuery or is it our local bug? Has anyone else encountered the same problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to troubleshoot your code?

Comment: I'm interested how you chose 1.6.1, since 1.6.4 is the most recent of the 1.6 line. Does it work properly with 1.6.4?

Comment: It's a system designer chooses what to use instead of me, being developer :)

Answer (score -2):

That is actually not the proper way of getting an element.
Although it works on some cases/browsers, that's not utilizing the power of jQuery actually at all.

$("#elem") should be used instead so that jQuery can apply the applicable code to get the element.

Also check if u accidentaly run the code before the element sets in DOM.